# Google API not returning Latitude and Longitude

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, ios8, mkmapview, mapkit

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode?output=dragdir&saddr=28.597693,77.374106&daddr=38.597347,87.374329 .

This link is not returning the required data. I am trying to draw the route between 2 points in IOS app. This link is suppose to return me the lattitude and longitude parameters between 2 points. Does any body has any idea regarding this?

Comment: FYI: According to Google's API terms and conditions you can't display their data without a Google map. If you're doing this in iOS 8 on a real MKMapView you'll have an Apple map and should not be using Google data's.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the result format: json/xml

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?output=dragdir&saddr=28.597693,77.374106&daddr=38.597347,87.374329

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?output=dragdir&saddr=28.597693,77.374106&daddr=38.597347,87.374329

But isn't the latitude and longitude the 2 numbers separated by comma inside the `saddrs` tag ?

```
saddr=28.597693,77.374106
latitude: 28.597693
longitude: 77.374106
```